# Computation branches on NTM

Tags: turing-machines, computability, nondeterminism

I would like to run the following string $w=011101$ on the following NTM and figure out the respective computation branches and whether it accepts or rejects that string.

$\text{Start: }(q_0) 011101 $

$0(q_3)11101$

$(q_1)011101$

$a) 0(q_{rej}) 11101 \:\:\:  b) 0(q_{acc}) 11101$

My questions are:

- Does the T.M continues on $b) 0(q_acc) 11101$ and reads a $1$, thus going to $q_2$ or it halts whenever it hits an accepting or rejecting state?
- Does the T.M accept the string above?

[image: NTM]

Comment: It does both, or it does whichever one eventually leads to an accepting state, depending on your interpretation. Since q_reject never leads to an accepting state we can ignore that branch unless it's the only branch left.

Answer (score 0):

The final states of a Turing machine (deterministic or not) have immediate effect and terminate the current computation. In your example, you have two final states $q_{acc}$ and $q_{rej}$ which will terminate any computation that reaches one of those state.

Now since there exists a computation that reaches the state $q_{acc}$, your non-deterministic Turing machine will terminate and accept the input. Therefore, your input $w = 011101$ will be accepted.